# Ajax Calls with Sitecore

Tags: ajax, sitecore

Currently I've read this resource http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/06/tutorial-how-to-make-ajax-call-in.html on how to make ajax calls with Sitecore. But I can see this getting out of hand as far as adding Routes to the Routes.config. What alternatives are there to adding routes to the config? Or maybe some way to read them in from a config file? Is there perhaps some "natural" way for Sitecore to pick up the controller and action?

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore way to register routes is do the same that is described in article, but call it not from App_start folder. It should be called from one of processors in *initialize* pipeline.

As example you could open your */sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx*, find *initialize* pipeline definition and look on *Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc*, *Sitecore.Cintel.Client.Initialization.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Cintel.Client* or *Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Cintel* processors. Actually they do the same that is described in article that you have provided, difference is only in place where it is called.

P.S. As for me call from *initialize* pipeline have one benefit: you can control order of routes collection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) and make use of Attribute Routing, which will allow you to simply decorate your Classes and Controller Action with the route information and it is automatically hooked together.

You'll need to configure it with some additional code for Sitecore 8:

http://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/using-web-api-2-attribute-routing-with-sitecore/

http://wp-bartbovendeerdtcom.azurewebsites.net/sitecore-8-webapi-v2-mvc-and-attribute-routing/